# multipart form-data in moya with an int value in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, multipartform-data, moya

I'm trying to send a form data with post request to API with moya.
I searched the stack overflow and found some questions which they were similar to mine but I'm getting some error which I'll post it below.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50089462/9930790) and [This](https://github.com/Moya/Moya/blob/master/docs/Examples/MultipartUpload.md) are the two references that I read for my problem 
[![**These are the keys that I'm supposed to send**][3]][3]

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Data'

even I tried the code below:

```
 let memberIdData = memberID.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? Data()




let data = ["id":0,
                    "AddressLine":EntAddressLine.text,
                    "CityId":selectedCity,
                    "Mobile":EntMobile.text,
                    "PostalCode":EntPostalCode.text,
                    "ProvinceId":selectedProvince,
                    "Tel":EntTelephone.text] as [String : Any]
```

how exactly should I fix this

**UPDATE:**

```
    case .AddAddress(let data):
            var multipartData = [MultipartFormData]()
            for (key, value) in params! {
                let Provience = MultipartFormData.init(provider: .data("\(data)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!), name: "id")

                multipartData.append(Provience)
            }
            return .uploadMultipart(multipartData)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nothing special you should do!!!

```
public var task: Task {
    switch self {

    case .AddAddress(let data):
        return .requestParameters(parameters: data, encoding: URLEncoding.default)

    }

    }
```

try this , this should help

Comment: It worked but when I try to get the data I sent i shows an option at beginning of the strings

Comment: I think you should ask a new question

Answer (score 6):

Multipart Form Data cant have other types than Data.
So it'd be better to hold a dictionary with type [String:String] and convert it to Data.
Example:

```
var task: Task {
    case .... {
        let params: [String:String] = ["id":"0", //convert to string
                                       "AddressLine":EntAddressLine.text,
                                       "CityId":"\(selectedCity)",  //convert to string
                                       "Mobile":EntMobile.text,
                                       "PostalCode":EntPostalCode.text,
                                       "ProvinceId":"\(selectedProvince)",//convert to string
                                       "Tel":EntTelephone.text]

        var multipartData = [MultipartFormData]()
        for (key, value) in params {
            let formData = MultipartFormData(provider: .data(value.data(using: .utf8)!), name: key)
            multipartData.append(formData)
        }

        return .uploadMultipart(multipartData)
    }
    ....
}
```

===============
EDIT:

For non-multipart requests:

```
var task: Task {
        case .... {
            let params: [String:Any] = ["id":0,
                                        "AddressLine":EntAddressLine.text,
                                        "CityId":selectedCity,
                                        "Mobile":EntMobile.text,
                                        "PostalCode":EntPostalCode.text,
                                        "ProvinceId":selectedProvince,
                                        "Tel":EntTelephone.text]

            return .requestParameters(parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        }
        ....
}

var headers: [String : String]? {
    return ["Content-Type":"application/json"]
}
```

Comment: I did whatever you said and still, I have the problem.

Comment: @ItanHant What problem exactly do you have?

Comment: I get 200 , but in response body if It returns "false"  it means there is a problem with the data we send and I check with the admin and she said that It must be a form data request

Comment: "Form Data" and "Multipart Form Data" are different things. Please check with your admin if it should be just "Form Data" or "Multipart Form Data"

Comment: what are the required for form data?

Comment: @ItanHant Also check the "Content-Type" that you are sending.

Comment: I just added a photo, could pls check that

Comment: @ItanHant Could you also add a screenshot of "Headers" tab?

Comment: @ItanHant What "Content-Type" is expecting your server?

Comment: I'm not sending ,but postman is sending "  "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
"

Comment: "content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW                  is this enough?

Comment: I can't understand the reason for using multipart form data for this request. 
Usually, you use multipart when you upload a file to the server, but in your case, you're just doing a simple request. Why just not to ask your admin to switch to "application/json" ? :)

Comment: I told him before, but she said it would be needed in future  :)

Comment: Then you definitely should use my first solution. But for debugging the request that you're sending, I suggest you use Charles Proxy Debugging Tool. https://www.charlesproxy.com 
Install the app, and run your app in a simulator and see what CharlesProxy logged in "Headers" and "Content" sections, and you will find the mistake that you're looking for :) 
Good luck!

Comment: As I'm using moya, it shows all the log that I need!

Comment: That's true, though CharlesProxy shows much more info. It's up to you

Comment: but I didn't understand what anything in Charles as I used,

Comment: what is FormDataProvider?